# How to setup auto-reply for group email in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, auto-reply

I have help-desk group email that needs to setup for auto-reply, so how can I do it? And email server is exchange server.

Comment: Would be better suited for SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know; you can't set it up exactly like this.  I've done it before 2 different ways:

1.)  Add a dummy mailbox to your group for admin purposes only, and configure that mailbox to send out an auto-reply

2.)  Create a mailbox for the email address you have and configure it to send out an auto-reply.  Then; set up a rule to forward messages sent to that box onto your distribution group.

(Sorry if my syntax is a little off; I've been out of the admin game for a while)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good, yet simple, way to accomplish auto-responding to a distribution list providing you are using either Exchange 2007 or 2010.

From the Exchange Management Console:

1. First, setup a "dummy" account such as No-Reply mailbox. Open up the Organization tab - Click on Hub Transport, then Transport Rules
2. From here, you can create a new rule where any messages sent to a particular distribution list are "blind-copied" to the dummy mailbox mentioned above. Using an Outlook client, you can then open up this mailbox and create a "have server reply using..." rule.

Simple, straightforward, and works like a charm.

Comment: Exchange 2010 does not have "sent to distribution list" rule trigger, it expands the list and then "sent to DL's address" does not trigger anymore.